# method returns false when it should return true

Tags: php, oop, exception, methods, pdo

I can't work out why this method keeps returning false. I'm checking the length of a password entered. It is definitely over 5 characters.The name of the input field is correct. But it always throws the exception `throw new Exception("Password must contain at least 6 characters.");`.

method:

```
public function checkPassword(){
        if(strlen($this->post_data['register_password']) > 5){

        }else{
            throw new Exception("Password must contain at least 6 characters.");
        }
    }
```

calling:

```
if( isset($_POST['register-submit'])){  
    $error = '';
    $register = new register($_POST, $dbh);
        try {
            if($register->checkUsername()){
                if($register->checkPassword()){

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error .= '<span style="color:red;">' . $e->getMessage() . '</span>';
        }
}
```

edit: added more of the class

```
public $post_data = array();
private $dbh;
public function __construct($post_data, PDO $dbh){
        $this->error = array();
        $this->post_data = array_map('trim', $post_data);
        $this->dbh = $dbh;

    }
```

Comment: is your function throwing an Error?

Comment: What's in `$this->post_data['register_password']`?

Comment: Erm... You are considering the passwords to be the same if their length is the same. So "fish" and "j2o3" would be considered the same.

Comment: @crm: What does `var_dump( $this->post_data['register_password'] );` output?

Comment: @Kolink I would assume this is used for registration purposes. He is just validating the password has at least 6 characters to ensure a strong enough password for creating an account.

Comment: @Amal where do I put that var_dump please?

Comment: @crm Also, you should probably post the code for the constructor function. That is where I would assume that the `$_POST` data that is passed in gets saved to `$this->post_data` property in the class.

Comment: @crm Put the var_dump at the top of the `checkPassword` function.

Comment: @Amal var_dump = `NULL`

Comment: Then there's your problem.

Comment: I dont see why it should return null though?

Comment: Try putting `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of the calling code. Make sure you have the right variable name for password. I notice you have `register-submit` for the submit button and `register_password` for the password. Did you mix the hyphen (`-`) with an underscore (`_`)?

Comment: @Jonathan BRB just taking a walk out of this 5 story window. (Feel free to leave that as the correct answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of the calling code. Make sure you have the right variable name for password. I notice you have `register-submit` for the submit button and `register_password` for the password. Did you mix the hyphen (`-`) with an underscore (`_`)?

Comment: Nice catch. Would have been better if you state it instead of posing a question, though. +1 anyway!

Comment: @AmalMurali I just copied my comment from above. It was enough to get the point across and give an answer to accept/close.

Answer (score 2):

You create the class `register`, with `$_POST`, then use `$this->post_data` to fetch `register_password`. I doubt that there is something wrong with `$this->post_data`, add `var_dump` to debug:

```
public function checkPassword(){
    if(strlen($_POST['register_password']) > 5){
        return true;

    }else{
        // for debug
        // var_dump($this->post_data['register_password']);
        throw new Exception("Password must contain at least 6 characters.");
    }
}
```

add `var_dump` to debug the `__construct`:

```
public function __construct($post_data, PDO $dbh){
    $this->error = array();
    $this->post_data = array_map('trim', $post_data);
    var_dump($this->post_data);
    $this->dbh = $dbh;
}
```

Comment: Good point, he is not actually returning true. Not returning anything, which means the return result is null which is falsy. Probably would be better to put an explanation of the code.

Comment: It would be nice if this answer explained that fact instead of just dumping a code fragment.

Comment: @srain: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832861/method-returns-false-when-it-should-return-true#comment27782301_18832861) comment by the OP. It's returning `NULL`.

Comment: @AmalMurali, I think there is something wrong with `$this->post_data`, So you can use `$_POST` instead of `$this->post_data`, I updated the answer. Or you can paste the `__construct` function of class `register` or the whole class. We will check it.

Comment: @AmalMurali, add `var_dump` to debug the `__construct`, paste the output in you question, I think the `register_password` will be `null`.

Comment: @srain: Err what? I'm just a commenter. I think the OP just [went out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832861/method-returns-false-when-it-should-return-true/18832992?noredirect=1#comment27782629_18832861) of the 5 story window (or something).